# How to access the AWS APIGateway based on the cognito user pool group roles

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

I created a user pool and added 2 user Groups. Registered 2 users and attached to different groups.
The groups having different roles, 1 role having a policy, that can execute the Lambda function with resource **GET /countries**
another role having another policy, that can execute the Lambda function with the resource **POST /countries**.
But both the users can access both the resources by passing the ID token as the Authorization header.

I used policies like

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:us-west-1:12098989898:sdsds56ffdf/*/GET/countries"
    }]
}
```

Do I need to add any conditions to the Policy? Why the users can access the 2 resources. How can we restrict based on the user pool groups?

Answer (score 2):

The default cognito authorizer that you used only checks if the token is valid and belongs to the correct user pool. If you want to check for group as well, you can use a custom lambda authorizer that passes the token to cognito using sdk and checks what group the user belongs to.

Or you can change the authorizer a bit to make it send groupname to the backend where you can make conditional check.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-enable-cognito-user-pool.html

Comment: Isn't there any other solution than writing our custom authorizer? Then why did they introduce the user groups and assign roles to the user groups in cognito?

Comment: User groups and roles can be used once you generate temporary access key and secret key for the user to authenticate the SDK calls. This can be used both in the front end as well as back end. Cognito tokens aren't just meant for securing APIs after all.

Comment: So, what would be the solution to my problem? Can we call API gateway through the SDK?

Comment: If you want to use the authorizer to validate using the policy that you have defined. You'll need to change the authorizer to IAM instead of cognito and then pass the temporary access key and secret key. That will be way more risky than just defining your own custom authorizer.

Comment: Can you see? as per the document https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-scenarios.html#scenario-api-gateway, We are able to provide access to api gateway based on the IAM roles associated with the groups with using the Cognito Authorizer.

Comment: Follow the link under that documentation for using API gateway with cognito and you will end up here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-integrate-with-cognito.html

It states you need to make  the federated iditentity call to get temporary aws credentials and then use the AWS-IAM authorizer instead of cognito authorizer. Default Cognito authorizer will ONLY check if your token is valid for a user pool.